# OptaPlanner Construction heuristics initialise on -1

Tags: optaplanner

As I understand it, Optaplanner is initialising entities with value `null` when using construction heuristics. I have the following setup:

```
@PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {"dayRange"})
  public Integer getDay() {
    return day;
  }
```

Is there a way to tell Optaplanners construction heuristics to initialise the field `day`, when it holds the value -1 instead of `null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `@PlanningVariable(reinitializeVariableEntityFilter = ...)` you can probably do that.

But don't do that, because nobody does that and therefore such an approach is uncommon (think testing and production usage). It could cause trouble, confusion and complexity later down the line (think continuous planning, real-time planning, overconstrained planning). **Just use `null` to indicate that a planning variable is uninitialized.**
After the Construction Heuristic, all variables will be non null.